# Why dtors of functors called twice (multitimes), when passed to a thread as the argument for Function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, libstdc++, stdthread

I'm having this question because of the following example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct foo{
    foo() = default;
    void operator()(int i) const {}
    ~foo(){std::cout<<"dtor\n";}
} foo;

typedef struct bar{
    bar() = default;
    bar(const bar&) {std::cout<<"copy\n";}
    bar(bar&&) {std::cout<<"move\n";}
    void operator()(const foo& f, int k) const {f(k);}
    ~bar(){std::cout<<"bar\n";}
} bar;

int main(){
    foo f_1, f_2;
    bar b_1, b_2;
    int i(0), j(0);
    while(i++!=2){
            std::thread t(b_1, std::cref(f_1), i);
            b_2(f_2, j);
            t.join();
    }
    int dummy(0);
    std::cin >> dummy;
}
```

which yields (both gcc and clang give the same result)

```
copy
move
bar
bar
copy
move
bar
bar
0
bar
bar
dtor
dtor
```

, where the 0 is user input.

So the dtor for bar--the argument for [Function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)--is called twice after the tread finishes its job (for each iteration). What I don't understand, is why twice instead of just once(for making the copy)?

In addition, is it possible to avoid the copy, in case the functor itself holds non-copiable resources or is expensive to be copied?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**
It's not necessarily twice as the original question asked, see Praetorian's answer below, where 3 dtor calls and 2 moves are involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing an lvalue (`b_1`) to the `std::thread` constructor, so it'll copy that argument. I've modified your example so that it's easier to follow what's going on. Note that the `while` condition has been changed so that it only executes once.

```
typedef struct foo{
    foo() = default;
    void operator()(int i) const {}
//    ~foo(){std::cout<<"dtor\n";}
} foo;

typedef struct bar{
    bar()           {std::cout<<"bar      " << this << '\n';}
    bar(const bar&) {std::cout<<"bar copy " << this << '\n';}
    bar(bar&&)      {std::cout<<"bar move " << this << '\n';}
    void operator()(const foo& f, int k) const {f(k);}
    ~bar()          {std::cout<<"~bar     " << this << '\n';}
} bar;

int main(){
    foo f_1, f_2;
    bar b_1, b_2;
    int i(0), j(0);
    while(i++!=1){
            std::cout << "---- 1 ----\n";
            std::thread t(b_1, std::cref(f_1), i);
            std::cout << "---- 2 ----\n";
            b_2(f_2, j);
            t.join();
            std::cout << "---- 3 ----\n";
    }
}
```

On [gcc this produces the output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1fcb2780657d6a2) (annotations are mine)

```
bar      0x7fffbcc2156c   // b_1 constructed
bar      0x7fffbcc2156d   // b_2 constructed
---- 1 ----
bar copy 0x7fffbcc21580   // std::thread ctor makes copy of b_1
bar move 0x162a038        // that copy is moved by std::thread impl
~bar     0x7fffbcc21580   // moved from object is destructed
---- 2 ----
~bar     0x162a038        // bar object owned by thread instance is destroyed
---- 3 ----
~bar     0x7fffbcc2156d   // b_2 is destroyed
~bar     0x7fffbcc2156c   // b_1 is destroyed
```

The [output from clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03e5e792bb8fb521) is identical.

There are a couple of different options if you want to avoid that copy. You can wrap the `b_1` instance in `std::reference_wrapper` before passing it to `std::thread`.

```
std::thread t(std::cref(b_1), std::cref(f_1), i);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d106a88ba2dfceb8)

Or you can allow the `std::thread` constructor to move the `b_1` instance.

```
std::thread t(std::move(b_1), std::cref(f_1), i);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db26e05f1e978d13). In this case you'll incur the internal move construction performed by the `std::thread` implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Praetorian. Just a quick note: it seems that only 1 move is called and 2 dtors calls happened in my gcc (Cygwin port 4.8.3), aka similar to clang's behavior.

Comment: @CloudyTrees That was a mistake on m part, I passed `-fno-elide-constructors` to gcc accidentally and that was causing the extra move construction.